# How to install django in windows 10

Tags: python, django, anaconda

I'm using anaconda interpreter, can you please tell me how to install django by creating conda environment in different drive (other than C drive).

Thank you

Comment: https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-python-django-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `-p` or `--prefix` argument in `conda create` to save the environment to a specific location.

```
conda create -p D:/path/to/my/env django
```

The only difference here is that the environment will not be in the list provided by anaconda and thus has to be explicitly activated with its path.

For example this is what it looks like on OS X:

```
conda create -p ~/Desktop/test -y -q django


Package plan for installation in environment /Users/grr/Desktop/test:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    ca-certificates: 2017.08.26-ha1e5d58_0
    certifi:         2018.1.18-py36_0
    django:          1.11.8-py36hd476221_0
    libcxx:          4.0.1-h579ed51_0
    libcxxabi:       4.0.1-hebd6815_0
    libedit:         3.1-hb4e282d_0
    libffi:          3.2.1-h475c297_4
    ncurses:         6.0-hd04f020_2
    openssl:         1.0.2n-hdbc3d79_0
    pip:             9.0.1-py36h1555ced_4
    python:          3.6.4-hc167b69_1
    pytz:            2017.3-py36hf0bf824_0
    readline:        7.0-hc1231fa_4
    setuptools:      38.4.0-py36_0
    sqlite:          3.21.0-h3efe00b_0
    tk:              8.6.7-h35a86e2_3
    wheel:           0.30.0-py36h5eb2c71_1
    xz:              5.2.3-h0278029_2
    zlib:            1.2.11-hf3cbc9b_2

# conda environments:
#
Tensorflow               /Users/grr/anaconda/envs/Tensorflow
cbc                      /Users/grr/anaconda/envs/cbc
py27                     /Users/grr/anaconda/envs/py27
py35                     /Users/grr/anaconda/envs/py35
root                  *  /Users/grr/anaconda

source activate ~/Desktop/test
(/Users/grr/Desktop/test) Diouf: grr ~ $
```

On Windows you would just omit `source` during activation.